# Unable to run pushtest Apigee sample

Tags: apigee

I am trying to run the pushtest sample that ships with the iOS SDK. In the .m file I have replaced the org name, app name and notifier name( which I have named 'apple'). I have the provisioning set up for my iPad. When I run the code, I don't see any window asking me to allow push notifications. On clicking the push to this device, the terminal spits out this error:

```
    2014-01-30 14:04:20.525 Push Test[2970:60b] displaying alert. title: Error, message: {"error":"unauthorized","timestamp":1391119457656,"duration":0,"exception":"org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException","error_description":"Subject does not have permission [applications:post:ed031740-7e90-11e3-a906-25e89414fcd7:/notifications]"}
```

I believe this is because the app has not obtained push permission, however, the alert window asking for this was not presented in the first case. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you put valid values for `orgName`, `appName`, and `notifier` variables in `AppDelegate.m`?

Answer (score 1):

```
"error":"unauthorized"`
```

This is an indication that your request requires authentication and you're not authorized to access the endpoint.

Push notifications out of the box require authentication - either an access_token (recommended) or client_id/secret. Try including the access_token in your header (instructions [here](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-api-requests)).

If you want to disable authentication, you can add the `GUEST` role to `/notifications` (instructions [here](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/managing-access-defining-permission-rules)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permissions to your application role:

curl -X POST "https://api.usergrid.com///roles/ -d '{"name":"nameforrole","title":"titleforrole","permission" : "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE:/users/me/**"}'